# Stack overflow IE8 error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, primefaces

I have problem with p:calendar(Primefaices tag for date) and IE8. When i click on the input text, the IE window freezes and then launches 'Stack overflow in line 16' error. I checkout out the Javascript debug in IE8, it seems that an infinite call was launched. The problem does not occur with FireFox, and  Chrome.

Here the code

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date2}" id="popupCal" />
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is your primefaces version? Do you have any dateSelect event configured?

Comment: my primefaces version is 3.5. No i don t have any dateSelect event configured.

Comment: Does this also happen in your IE8 Browser when you open the calendar on the [primefaces showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarHome.jsf) ? I have an IE 8 as well and all calendar examples on the showcase do work for me. As far as I know PF 3.5 dropped support for IE7 but IE8 should work.

Comment: No, it works fine with primefaces showcase page.